# When parsing Summary information, getting Type Mismatch Error

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am working on a Recipe App, i am able to parse the json data but am stuck on how to implement a section of each Recipe:

**recipe.json**

Attached is the sample section of a Recipe:

```
{
    "title": "Crumble",
    "image" : "crumble",
    "description": "Delicious!",
    "prepTime": " 7 minutes",
    "cookTime": " 3 minutes",
    "servings": 4,
    "summary": [  //<--- Need help with this section!
        {"rating":"5"},
        {"serves":"4"},
        {"preparation":"7 minutes"},
        {"cooking" : "3 minutes"}
    ],
    "ingredients": [
        {"name": "Apple Pie Filling, peeled and thinly-sliced", "num": 800, "unit": "grams"},
        {"name": "Ground Cinnamon", "num": 1, "unit": "teaspoon"}
        {"name": "Double Cream, to serve"}
    ],
    "directions":
    [
        "Combine apple, cinnamon and lemon rind in a bowl.",
        "Sprinkle muesli on top of apple mixture. "
    ]
},
```

**Recipe model**

```
class Recipe: Identifiable, Decodable {
var id:UUID?
var title: String
var image: String
var description: String
var prepTime: String
var cookTime: String
var servings: Int
var summary: [String:String]
var ingredients: [Ingredient]
var directions: [String]
```

}

class Ingredient: Identifiable, Decodable {

```
var id:UUID?
var name:String
var num:Int?
var denom:Int?
var unit:String?
```

}

From the above .json file, i have created my model.

I am able to parse and retrieve all of the above, except for the 'summary' section.

If i run my app with the above info for the SUMMARY, i get this error:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Swift.String>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: “Index 0”, intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: “summary”, intValue: nil)], debugDescription: “Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but found an array instead.”, underlyingError: nil))

BUT, if i comment out the 'SUMMARY' info in my Model - Recipe.swift file, no crashes and all the other info is received when parsing local json file.

**Am i not writing it correctly in my Model?  How can i get this to work so i can access it for my app without crashing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the error message carefully

> Expected to decode Dictionary<String, String> but **found an array** instead

tells you that the value for key `summary` is an array so you have to write

```
var summary: [[String:String]]
```

Comment: Noob at this, just learning. I just didn’t know how to write the Dictionary

Comment: This type is pretty confusing and weird. An array of dictionaries and each dictionary contains only **one** item is very unusual and inefficient.